# Переместить gradle dependencies в отдельный файл

Tags: android, gradle, зависимости

Коллеги, при сборке Android проекта использую несколько вариантов готовых файлов gradle, в которых собираются разные проекты на базе нескольких модулей с разными тасками.

Всё работает отлично, но для каждого файла gradle в каждом модуле приходится дублировать блок зависимостей

```
dependencies {

    implementation "com.android.support:design:$supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:$supportLibraryVersion"

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'

    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    ... // и так далее
    }
```

Иногда забывается, иногда пропускается, в общем бывает случается, что в каком то из гредлов остаются одни зависимости, когда везде уже обновили.

Естественно, правильным решением будет вынести это всё в какой то один файл.

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться, как это делается, потому что гуглопоиск **на тему gradle add dependencies from file** приводит меня только к работе с jar, что мне не нужно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пример от Google https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/versions.gradle

Затем используем так
Определяем в [versions.gradle](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/versions.gradle#L23)

```
ext.deps = [:]
def versions = [:]
versions.support = "27.1.1"

def support = [:]
support.annotations = "com.android.support:support-annotations:$versions.support"
support.app_compat = "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$versions.support"
```

В [build.gradle разных модулей](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/build.gradle#L70)

```
dependencies {
    implementation deps.support.app_compat
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!